# Highlight recyclerview item in custom layout (get focus)

Tags: android, android-tv

I'm developing an application for **Android TV**. I made a custom view where I represent list items (in RecyclerView).
How can I get a focus on my items and highlight them (a simple example would be wonderful)?

I did try to add

```
android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
android:focusable="true"
```

to `.xml` file, but I've not seen any changes.

**EDIT:** I want to get *focus* when navigating through items by dpad

Answer (score 0):

in youf adapter do something like this

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder viewHolder, int i) {

    viewHolder.YOUR_LAYOUT.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            // do whatever you want
            viewHolder.YOUR_LAYOUT.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ripple_effect);
        }
    });

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use setOnitemClicklistener on your listview or recycleview . This is how you can do this:

```
ListView lv = getListView();
setContentView(lv);
lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener()
{
@Override 
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View view,int position, long arg3)
{ 
    Toast.makeText(Activity.this, "" + position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

//========== Here you can change the color of selected item ========
TextView Tv_title = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.title);
Tv_title.setTextColor(Color.RED);
//====== Your can make any view color change here just like i did for textview ===


}
});
```

If still you are not getting focusable try using this solution :

Use `android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"` in your XML file of the first parent layout inside the list.

Comment: I did terrible formulation. I want to get focus when navigating through items by dpad, not by clicking.